# Modal Layout Responsive in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-flex-layout

I have a problem on the responsiveness of using modals in Angular Material. How can i make it look good on small screens. It doesn't have to be mat-grid

Pls see this stackblitz link

[Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-veielt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
      width: "650px",
      height: "380px"
    });
  }
```

Comment: with `include-media` you can do responsive interface in more succinct way, in example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-responsive?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.scss

Comment: @Radik. Is that another package?

Comment: yes i upgrade it to latest to enable scss files

Comment: Great! Its good package but it makes your app more larger if you rely on many packages. But anyway. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-unf8yk)You can use media query in style.css

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal .mat-grid-tile {
     width:100% !important;
     position:relative!important;  
     left:0 !important; 
  }
  .modal .mat-form-field {
    width: 100%
  }
  .modal .mat-radio-button {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .modal .mat-raised-button.mat-warn {
       margin:5px
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try if this is what you want:

```
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalComponent, {
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh",
        maxWidth: "650px",
        maxHeight: "900px"
    });
```

For small devices you get the dialog 'as a page' with no border.
For bigger devices the size is limited to a given value.

Comment: That's not really responsive, is it?

Comment: It's responsive. Small devices -> full page,  bigger screens -> smaller dialog

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use responsive layout, dont use mat-grid-list